# Importing code from eclipse to android studio giving error

Tags: eclipse, android-studio

Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\k\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 42

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> C:\Users\K\StudioProjects\MyCRM\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\homepage.png: Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\K\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- update the android studio with latest version available
- restart the studio